# validation of specific string pattern in entity framework

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to make users to enter this pattern in textboxes in asp.net mvc3:

```
[digit][digit]Code[digit][digit][digit][letter][digit][digit]
```

I prefer to use annotations but I could not find proper one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [RegularExpressionAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.regularexpressionattribute.aspx) attribute

Example taken from MSDN

```
[MetadataType(typeof(CustomerMetaData))]
public partial class Customer
{


}

public class CustomerMetaData
{

    // Allow up to 40 uppercase and lowercase 
    // characters. Use custom error.
    [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z''-'\s]{1,40}$", 
         ErrorMessage = "Characters are not allowed.")]
    public object FirstName;

    // Allow up to 40 uppercase and lowercase 
    // characters. Use standard error.
    [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z''-'\s]{1,40}$")]
    public object LastName;
}
```